# How to specify GPKG Driver in GDAL/OGR under C++?

Tags: gdal, ogr, geopackage

Working under CentOS (Linux), we have run up against the 4GB shapefile (dbf) limitation in our Monte Carlo model. We've decided to switch to GeoPackage to output our point attributes. I cannot find a reference on what GDAL/OGR driver to ask for under C++.

If I specify"GKPG" as a driver name, I get a null value returned from `GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName`. I am linking with GDAL 2.3.2.
Using the command:
    $ ogrinfo --formats |grep  GPKG

I get:

```
GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage.
```

I assume this means that we linked with GEOPKG (and sqllite3) when we installed the package, but I am checking with IT to try to find out more. Apologies that I don't know how to make my code show with line feeds below:

My stripped down code below:

```
#include <ogr_feature.h>
#include "ogrsf_frmts.h"
GDALDriver  *Driver;
int main()
{
 const char *Seed_drv = "ESRI Shapefile"; //Results in valid Driver below. 
 OGRRegisterAll(); // Register Drivers
 Driver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(Seed_drv); //Driver:Valid
}
```

However:...

```
 const char *Seed_drv = "GPKG"; // Results in NULL myDriver below.
 OGRRegisterAll(); // Register Drivers
 myDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(Seed_drv); // Driver:NULL
```

Comment: How I'm linking:# Optimise:
 g++ -O3 -Wall -std=c++0x $1.cpp -o $1 -L/usr/local/lib -lgdal -L/usr/lib64 -I/usr/local/include/ 

 # Debug:
 g++ -ggdb -Wall -std=c++0x -rdynamic -o $1 $1.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lgdal -L/usr/lib64 -I/usr/local/include/

Answer (score 1):

To check availability of GPKG execute following command in console:

```
ogrinfo --formats
```

It is expected the following line in output:

```
GPKG -raster,vector- (rw+vs): GeoPackage
```

The driver details, create and open options can be found at  [GPKG driver page](https://gdal.org/drv_geopackage.html)

Comment: I received the expected result when I entered your command above. I've updated my question with the code I'm using for ESRI Raster vs GPKG. I need to know whether I need to rebuild GDAL Even though I got the correct response from the info query.